# How to perform an euclidian division in a Finite Field?

Tags: packages, algorithm, finite-fields

I am quite new to mathematica, I am looking for a function similar to `QuotientRemainder[]` but which works with finite fields as implemented by the `FiniteFields` [package](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FiniteFields/guide/FiniteFieldsPackage.html) (**update : or with any other package which handles finite fields**). The input should be two elements of a finite field and the output should be the quotient and the remainder of the euclidian division of the two elements.

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a compelling reason to use that package? It is not maintained and is known to not play nice with built in functions such as `Together`.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau absolutely none, I am just looking for a way to perform an euclidian division in a finite field, I just thought the `FiniteFields` package handled everything related to finite fields. I update my question.

Comment: There are a few possibilities. If your field is a prime field, simplest is to use `PolynomialQuotientRemainder` with a modulus set. If you are working over more general finite fields then it won't be quite so simple. I guess best would be to post an example or two showing what you have in mind.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I am working with "general" finite fields like $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})/(1+X^2+X^3)$, my elements would therefore be polynomials in the quotient field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could use `PolynomialReduce` for this. We just add the extension-defining polynomial to the reducing one (the divisor). Here is an example.

```
extpoly = x^3 + x^2 + 1;
p1 = (x^2 + 1)*y^5 + (x + 1)*y^4 + (x^2 + x)*y^2 + y + (x^2 + x + 1);
p2 = y^4 + x^2*y^3 + (x^2 + 1)*y + 1;

{{q1, q2}, r} = PolynomialReduce[p1, {p2, extpoly}, {y, x}, Modulus -> 2]

(* Out[106]= {{1 + x + x^2 + x^4 + y + x^2 y, 
  1 + x + y + x y + x^2 y + x^3 y + y^2 + x y^2 + x^2 y^3 + x^3 y^3}, 
 1 + x + x^2 + x^2 y} *)
```

So the quotient is `q1`, modulo the polynomial that defines the extension. And the remainder is `r`.

Check this:

```
PolynomialMod[p1 - {q1, q2}.{p2, extpoly}, 2]

(* Out[111]= 1 + x + x^2 + x^2 y *)
```

Comment: Could you take a look at the first heading [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/130756/12)?  It's not the sort of 'bug' I would report. It' internal stuff and probably not even a bug.  But maybe worth a glance for you?

Comment: @Szabolcs I  do not have a strong opinion on this myself. I sent a link to some developers who might be more familuar with the function, in case they see cause to comment, add documentation or the like.